# Trouble using add_row with prettytable

Tags: python, prettytable

I am trying to format an array using the `prettytable` library. Here is my code:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
arrayHR = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print ("arrayHR:", arrayHR)
x = PrettyTable(["Heart Rate"])
for row in arrayHR:
    x.add_row(row)
```

This results in the following error:

```
arrayHR: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\aag\Documents\Python\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    x.add_row(row)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\prettytable.py", line 817, in add_row
    if self._field_names and len(row) != len(self._field_names):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks Sundar. Your suggestion works. However, prettytable will format each value of the array as a field in its own column. This may be desirable in certain cases. Jonrsharpe's method results in a vertical column, which in my case is the preferred behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/prettytable/wiki/Tutorial), `add_row` is expecting a `list`, *not an `int`*, as an argument. Assuming that you want the values in `arrayHR` to be the first value in each row, you could do:

```
x = PrettyTable(["Heart Rate"])
for row in arrayHR:
    x.add_row([row])
```

or adopt the `add_column` example, also from the documentation:

```
x = PrettyTable()
x.add_column("Heart Rate", arrayHR)
```