# PrettyTable for loop is telling me TypeError: PrettyTable.add_row() takes 2 positional arguments but 8 were given

Tags: python, for-loop, prettytable

I have been trying to figure out what the issue is and can't seem to figure it out.

```
valueRange = [j.value for i in copyRange for j in i]
vrCounter = 0
vrStep = 7
x.field_names = ["Jurisdiction","SPOC-Name", "Lines of Business","Market Area", "Consultant Personal Lines", "Consultant Business Lines", " ROC-Name"]

for i in range(0,len(valueRange)):
    x.add_row(valueRange[i], valueRange[i+1], valueRange[i+2], valueRange[i+3], valueRange[i+4], valueRange[i+5], valueRange[i+6])
print(x)
```

I ran the code without the `x.add_row()` function and it printed the values correctly. The `valueRange` list is just a bunch of keywords that match the `field_names`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as duplicate of [Trouble using add\_row with prettytable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23933170/trouble-using-add-row-with-prettytable), due to failure of passing a list of values to `add_row`.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the [docs](https://ptable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html), add_row() takes a list of values as an argument.

Enclose all the values in a list and it must work.

```py
x.add_row([valueRange[i], valueRange[i+1], valueRange[i+2], valueRange[i+3], valueRange[i+4], valueRange[i+5], valueRange[i+6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn out the issue was the for i in range(0,len(valueRange)): portion. So it wasn't possible to answer this question without complete information about that valueRange list. This list contained 28 (0-27) string values. The loop was stepping through the 0-27 range 1 at a time while trying to apply an i+number value to each one. This would quickly go out of bounds unless the step size matches the valueRange list.

The final solution looks like:

```
for i in range(0,len(valueRange),7):
    x.add_row(valueRange[i:i+7])
```